# Continuous email server Connection using JAVA Mail API

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail, massmail, mail-server

We are intended to develop a service, which always **stay connected** to email server, so that whenever a user triggers a mail, it will sent by using the connect instead of getting a **new connection** and sending the mail.
Is is possible that we always stay connection to email server using JAVA Mail API??.
kindly help me in this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you connect to SMTP server (also when using `javax.mail` API), you use a socket connection (see the src of [SMTPTransport and Transport classes](http://www.google.com/codesearch#ojJ6TKlKTCM/trunk/mail/src/java/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.java&type=cs)). Sockets let you connect to a remote server and that connection remains open until explicitly closed. This means that theoreticaly you could create a connection and them reuse it.

However, many SMTP servers are pretty evil and will kill the connection [if you are using it "too slow"](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_connection_reuse_time_limit) or [if you try to resuse your SMTP session to often](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_connection_cache_reuse_limit). (I looked up [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) settings for you.)

The Java Mail API allows you to create the connection and close it whenever you want to. Smth. like this:

```
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect();
        transport.sendMessage(msg, addressArray);
        // you can do transport.close(); later
```

However, because of the fact how the SMTP servers are, you can't just execute `connect()` once and forget it. At most, what you can do, is properly handle forced disconnects by reconnecting again. There is a notification mechanism in the Java Mail API to do that (take a look at the usage of the `notifyConnectionListeners` method)

Comment: thanks you for your quick reply, i'll check this and come back to you.

Comment: Hi, i tried the above code, its working fine, but one issue is there. if i want send continuously message using the same connection as Message type as html(MinmeMessage and MimeBodyPart), the previous message is appended in the next mail. Do you know the reason why its appended.

Comment: Hi, Ignore the above comment,i tried the above code, its working fine, thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

> However, because of the fact how the SMTP servers are, you can't just
>   execute connect() once and forget it. At most, what you can do, is
>   properly handle forced disconnects by reconnecting again.

Agreed!

You can in fact reuse the JavaMail SMTP connection with below logic:

```
Transport transport = null;
MimeMessage message = null;

Properties prop = new Properties();
// load all smtp properties

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);
transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

for (EachMail eachMail : list) {
    if (!transport.isConnected()) {
        if (port != null && port.length() > 0) {
            transport.connect(host, Integer.parseInt(port), "<username>", "<password>");
        } else {
            transport.connect(host, "<username>", "<password>");
        }
    }

    // set all mail attributes from eachMail object
    message.saveChanges();
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
}
```

Works like a charm. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you want an always up connection you should create your Transport outside of the sending method, but to avoid excpetions on sending (SMTPSendFailedException 421 Timeout data client) you should check if the transport is connected, and if not to connect it again befor sending:

```
 if (!transport.isConnected())//make sure the connection is alive
            transport.connect();
 transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
```